# Laravel Sail on Windows Subsystem for Linux (wsl)

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-sail

I was trying to create a new laravel app with laravel sail and I ran the following command on ubuntu 20.0.4:

---

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

---

But I got the following message:

docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
bash: line 16: cd: example-app: No such file or directory

Get started with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up

---

[Here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llyuj.png)

(No folder is created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a directory with capitals and spaces, i.e: `Sennay Files`. Use a different directory or rename it to: `Sennay_Files`.

You are working on the Windows file system from within WSL (i.e. /mnt/c). This will cause a significant performance hit, and issues like the one you are experiancing, consider using the WSL file system. You can change to the WSL file system by typing

```
cd ~
```